# Dynamic component, relative to an URL

Tags: angular, angular2-routing

Here is my app.html structure :

```
<div class="body">
   <div class="content">
      <router-outlet></router-outlet>
   </div>
   <aside>
      <!-- aside component here, relative to <router-outlet> -->
   </aside>
</div>
```

How can I dynamically add a component inside aside, based on the component inserted in router-outlet ?

For example :

- If the router-outlet is HomeComponent, I want the ChatboxComponent inside aside.
- If the router-outlet is NewsComponent, I want the ListNewsComponent inside aside.

Named router-outlet would do the job, but I dont want to add the extra syntax (outlet:path) inside my URL, as there can only be one aside component per primary router-outlet...

Answer (score 1):

I think one way to achive it is use `ComponentFactoryResolver` as shown below:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: `
    <div class="container">
       <div class="content">
          <router-outlet></router-outlet>
       </div>
       <aside>
          <template #vcRef></template>
       </aside>
    </div>
  `
})
export class AppComponent {
   asideMap = {
     '/': ChatboxComponent,
     '/home': ChatboxComponent,
     '/news': ListNewsComponent
   };
   @ViewChild('vcRef', { read: ViewContainerRef }) vcRef: ViewContainerRef;
   constructor(private router: Router, private resolver: ComponentFactoryResolver) {
     router.events
      .filter(event => event instanceof NavigationStart)
      .subscribe((event) => {
        const comp = this.asideMap[event.url];
        this.vcRef.clear();
        let compRef = this.vcRef.createComponent(this.resolver.resolveComponentFactory(comp));
        compRef.instance.param = event.url;
      });
   }
}
```

Don't forget to add `ChatboxComponent` and `ListNewsComponent` to `entryComponents` property of your module.

**[Plunker Example](https://plnkr.co/edit/hZj4L2RnYlcTS15GSaoz?p=preview)**

Comment: But what if I want to access route params inside the dynamic component ?

Comment: You can pass params as i shown above or just inject `Router` or `ActivatedRoute` in construcor your dynamic component and use it as usual